# How would one vectorize counting smaller numbers than current max in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to learn more about numpy and I would like to be able to use vectorization to more complicated functions. Example:
Write function that will go from left side of an numpy array to the right and count all numbers smaller than **current** max value. 
If I had to operate over builtin python list I would do:

```
def count_smaller_than_current_max(lst):
    max_value = -1
    result = 0
    for value in lst:
        if value > max_value:
            max_value = value
            result += 1
    return result - 1
```

For

```
>>> count_smaller_than_current_max([1, 2, 3, 5, 4])
3
>>> count_smaller_than_current_max([1, 2, 5, 3, 4])
2
```

Any ideas how to do it on numpy array with vectorization?

Comment: Your function is not counting all number smaller than current max, it's counting how many times you encounter a number that's more than everything before. The two concepts are not the same.

Comment: `count_smaller_than_current_max([1, 2, 3, 1, 5])` returns 3.  Is that a correct result?

Comment: @ScottBoston no.

Comment: @RockyLi what is the difference?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate accumulated max and then compare it with `a`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,5,4])
(a[1:] > np.maximum.accumulate(a)[:-1]).sum()
# 3

a = np.array([1,2,5,3,4])
(a[1:] > np.maximum.accumulate(a)[:-1]).sum()
# 2
```

Comment: This is correct answer for lists that have unique values.
For lists with duplicated values the solution would be to add '='
(a[1:] >= np.maximum.accumulate(a)[:-1]).sum()

Answer (score 1):

You could use [unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) together with [maximum.accumulate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html):

```
import numpy as np

print(len(np.unique(np.maximum.accumulate([1, 2, 3, 5, 4]))) - 1)
print(len(np.unique(np.maximum.accumulate([1, 2, 5, 3, 4]))) - 1)
```

**Output**

```
3
2
```